# Node - taking a URL and reformatting it as a POST

Tags: json, node.js, parsing

I'm trying to set my node server up to receive an encoded URL like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/room=office&light=light2&state=on
```

and then send it as a POST with the workload appropriately formatted as:

```
{room:'office', light:'light2', state: 'on'}
```

So far, I've parsed it so that it formats correctly:

```
 var postrelay=S(pathname).replaceAll('/', '{').s;
 var postrelay=S(postrelay).replaceAll('=', ':\'').s;
 var postrelay=S(postrelay).replaceAll('&', '\',').s;
 var postrelay= (postrelay + '\'}')  ;  

http.post('http://www.postdomain.com/', postrelay);
```

Can someone tell me what I need to change to make this work?  The console log shows my parsed json string to be valid, but it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include a question mark at the beginning of the query string:

```
http://www.domain.com/?room=office&light=light2&state=on
                      ^
```

Once you do that, just parse the URL with `url.parse` and pass in the resulting object:

```
> var parsed = url.parse('http://www.domain.com/?room=office&light=light2&state=on', true);
> parsed.query
{ room: 'office',
  light: 'light2',
  state: 'on' }
```

Comment: It still isn't working.  The json string works when I insert it, but not when parsed from the url.  Why is this happening?  I'm trying:     var parsed = url.parse(pathname, true);
  JSON.stringify(parsed.query); http.post('http://192.168.1.98:8888/', {parsed});

Comment: @user3147697: Did you fix your URL so that the query string is valid?

Comment: I mean when I manually insert it like this: http.post('http://192.168.1.98:8888/', {"room":"office","light":"light2","state":"on"});  it works.  I did make it valid.

Comment: @user3147697: You're confusing the JSON format with JavaScript objects. JSON is a data format. While it may look like a JavaScript object literal and can be directly evaluated into one, it is completely different. You only need to do `http.post(..., parsed.query)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not much of a node user, so my approach is probably way convoluted.  I just need a server that receives a URL with a string and forwards it back out as a post.